# How MySQL server is running with the google

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

When I tried to upload a bulk data for a table I get this Error.

```
ERROR 1290 (SQLSTATE HY000): The MySQL server is running with the google so it cannot execute this statement
```

The Command which I used for uploading a data in command line (google_sql.cmd)

```
sql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'C\:List.txt' INTO TABLE Associate_List FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Please help Me.
What syntax I have to use and how do I upload a data in bulk?

Answer (score 2):

Typing your error message in a search engine (for example Google) makes me think that you are using Google Cloud SQL and you are attempting to run a command that isn't supported, as explained in [Does Google Cloud SQL support all the features of MySQL?](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#supportmysqlfeatures):

> ### Unsupported MySQL statements:
>
> Sending any of the following types of SQL statements will generate an
>   error with the message **"Error 1290: The MySQL server is running with
>   the google option so it cannot execute this statement"**
>
> ```
> LOAD DATA INFILE
> SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE
> SELECT ... INTO DUMPFILE
> INSTALL PLUGIN ...
> UNINSTALL PLUGIN
> CREATE FUNCTION ... SONAME ...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To bulk load data, upload your data to Google Cloud Storage first and then import it from there. Please see https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/import_export